# Elements from same div overlapping on resize

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I got problem with 2 elements from my header since 3 days,and cannot fix it.The problem is there that my "Search-trigger" which is my search icon and "tablet-icon" which is icon which is showing only on given browser width,are overlapping.Even search icon is going beyond tablet icon when browser is really tiny width.I tried with `Float:right,left`and `position:absolue,relative` on both elements ,`overflow:auto` on site header,`margin:left,right`on elements and display properties on both elements `display:block` ,`display:inline-block;` Nothing works... i don't know where is the problem..

```css
/***********************************************
                  Header Style
************************************************/
.admin-bar .site-header {
  top: 32px;
}

.admin-bar .site-header.is-fixed {
  top: -47px;
}
@media screen and (min-width:640px) and (max-width:790px){
.admin-bar .site-header.is-fixed{
top :-44px;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width:413px) and (max-width:783px){
.admin-bar .site-header{
top: 35px;
}
}
.site-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
/***********************************************
             Search menu style
************************************************/
 .search-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  right:0.5em;
  top: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor:pointer;
  cursor:hand;
  display:inline-block;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .search-trigger {
    right: 0.8em;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width:783px){
.search-trigger{
top:26px;
}
}
.search-trigger:before {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-family: "ElegantIcons";
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  content: "\55"; 
/***********************************************
                  Icon Style
************************************************/
 .tablet-icon{
  position: absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  left:90%;
  top: 23px;
  width: 40px;
  float:right;
}
.tablet-icon:before{
  width: 100%;
  font-size:1.6em;
  font-family: "ElegantIcons";
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  content: "\61";
}
```

```html
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">  
<span class="tablet-icon"></span>
<a id="search-trigger" class="search-trigger"></a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you use position:fixed, position:absolut, and z-index. You have to change this in your media queries for each resolution.

Comment: But you haven't change position:fixed and absolute?

Comment: Will try it tomorrow and will write the result here,thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When I have resizing issues I replace as many px sizings as I can with %. That way when the screen resizes, the elements resize proportionately. i.e. Change out things at 50px with 5%

Comment: You might be right,i will change pixels and ems to % and will type back tomorrow if it is fixed,because im going to sleep,thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well i make the positions on my elements INSIDE the "" element to relative and `float:right;` and left my position of`<header>`to absolute,and it worked like a magic.